# Resize Charts made by App Script on google site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, image-resizing

I created a line chart using app script and inserted it on google site, it shows up fine on google site as the following screenshot, but I am just wondering if I could resize the chart to make it bigger so that all legends (e.g: store F) will fully show up. (It's like I could drag the chart and make it big in excel)

[image]

Here is the part of the code I used (copied from a tutorial) and changed a bit, I tried to use .setOption to change the width but nothing happened.

```
  var chart = Charts.newLineChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)
      .setTitle("Testing Chart")
      .setOption("width",1000)
      .build();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Testing Chart");
  app.add(chart)
  return app;
```

In terms of inserting the app script into google site, I did set up the width of "app script gadget" to 100% so I guess this is not the issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try app.setWidth(1000) instead

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance#setWidth(Integer)

Comment: @JagannathanAlagurajan  thx for the info!  but it seems like the UI was deprecated.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I use google visualization to build charts in my web apps. Maybe you can use the same?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the docs, you should try changing [`setOption()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/line-chart-builder#setoptionoption-value) to be like:

```
.setOption("theme", "maximized")
```

`maximized` from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) (in line with `theme`):

> Maximizes the area of the chart, and draws the legend and all of the labels inside the chart area. Sets the following options:

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
.setDimensions(800, 600)
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/area-chart-builder#setDimensions(Integer,Integer)